# How can I run mule not using java wrapper

Tags: mule, aix, itanium

I'm trying to run mule-3.1.2 on 64bit IBM AIX,  but the java wrapper can't be executed (Found but not executable.).
I'm sure I have set the right permission.
Besides, I also can't run mule on a ia64 machine, same problem.

So can I run the mule just as a java application not using the java wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to start Mule without using the wrapper: besides [embedding it in a java or web-application](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE3USER/Embedding+Mule+in+a+Java+Application+or+Webapp), you can also start `main()` on [`org.mule.MuleServer`](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/MuleServer.html).

**Edit: 1**

A good resource suggested by @rocwing is: [Configuring Mule to Run From a Script](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+Mule+to+Run+From+a+Script)

**Edit 2:**

Below is a script that can start Mule standalone: logging is not correctly configured and the shutdown sequence is a little... challenged, but it should get you started.

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in $MULE_HOME/lib/boot/*.jar
do MULE_CLASSPATH="$MULE_CLASSPATH":$f ; 
done

for f in $MULE_HOME/lib/mule/*.jar
do MULE_CLASSPATH="$MULE_CLASSPATH":$f ; 
done

for g in $MULE_HOME/lib/opt/*.jar
do MULE_CLASSPATH="$MULE_CLASSPATH":$g ;
done

java -Djava.endorsed.dir=$MULE_HOME/lib/endorsed -cp "$MULE_CLASSPATH" org.mule.MuleServer -config ~/my/mule-config.xml
```

Comment: thanks! [Configuring Mule to Run From a Script](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+Mule+to+Run+From+a+Script)

Comment: It seems doesn't work...  I use this:java -cp ./lib/mule;./lib/opt org.mule.MuleServer -config mule-config.xml, but can't run mule, the error is below: D:\mule-standalone-3.1.2>java -cp ./lib/mule;./lib/opt org.mule.MuleServer -conf
ig mule-config.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/MuleServer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.MuleServer
.....
Could not find the main class: org.mule.MuleServer.  Program will exit.

Comment: Adding a directory in the classpath doesn't add all the JARs it contains on the classpath: you need to add the JARs you need one by one (use a script to do that).

Comment: thank you for reply, I use this script: @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set MULE_CLASSPATH=%MULE_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
FOR %%c in ("%MULE_HOME%\lib\mule\*.jar") DO set MULE_CLASSPATH=!MULE_CLASSPATH!;%%c
FOR %%d in ("%MULE_HOME%\lib\opt\*.jar") DO set MULE_CLASSPATH=!MULE_CLASSPATH!;%%d
FOR %%e in ("%MULE_HOME%\lib\boot\*.jar") DO set MULE_CLASSPATH=!MULE_CLASSPATH!;%%e
echo %MULE_CLASSPATH%
java -cp "!MULE_CLASSPATH!" org.mule.MuleServer -config mule-config.xml  but nothing happens, no error and log, just quit

Comment: Looks like Windows shell, I won't be able to test this :( I'm surprised to see the JRE libs on the classpath, aren't they there by default? Also "nothing happens" is very surprising... I mean there should be an error or something written in the console from where you started the script.

Comment: I used this script on Linux:#!/bin/sh
for f in /df8003/home/soa/esb/mule-standalone-3.3.0/lib/mule/*.jar
do
  MULE_CLASSPATH="$MULE_CLASSPATH":$f
done
for g in /df8003/home/soa/esb/mule-standalone-3.3.0/lib/opt/*.jar
do
  MULE_CLASSPATH="$MULE_CLASSPATH":$g
done
java -cp "$MULE_CLASSPATH" org.mule.MuleServer -config mule-config.xml  The error is below:

Comment: [11-15 15:00:22] WARN  FileConnector [main]: MULE-1773: cannot configure maxDispatchersActive when using outputAppend. New value not set
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
        at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.remove(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:55)
        at java.lang.Runtime.removeShutdownHook(Runtime.java:220)
        at org.mule.MuleServer.unregisterShutdownHook(MuleServer.java:522)
        at org.mule.MuleServer.shutdown(MuleServer.java:453)
        at org.mule.MuleServer.run(MuleServer.java:303)

Comment: I just copied a mule-config.xml from apps directory, I'm not sure whether this is OK.

Comment: I've done a few changes to your script (missing /boot and endorsed dirs) and Mule starts and loads up the passed configuration. It's not 100% perfect but should get you going.